# Can i launch both IOS , Android and browsers in the same instance

Tags: java, selenium, appium

i want to automate an application that has both androids and IOS versions, application Admins side is  web-based if User change the anything from the admin side this change impact on the Android and IOS version, I do not know how i can automate my application ? can it is possible in the same instance i can launch Browser, IOS, and Android native apps ?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have 3 different WebDriver instances:

1. [AndroidDriver](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.html) - to orchestrate Andorid device (or emulator)
2. [IOSDriver](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSDriver.html) - to control iOS device (or simulator)
3. An appropriate [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) implementation for the desktop browser

Make sure to write [thread-safe code](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-safety) in particular:

- Use [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) pattern to avoid clashes between above 3 WebDrivers
- Avoid using [static fields and functions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things15/index.html) unless you explicitly need it
- Your tests must be [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science))

More information (including sample project you can use as a reference): [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer , i have worked on the web base applications and android basae application not on the IOS applications can u help me out to find the best solution for it ? i want change the settings from the admin side and validate on the android and IOS side that this change is correctly implemented ... can u send me the best tutorials for it ?